# Getting Angular to build with ESBuild

Tags: angular, esbuild

I'm running Angular `15.0.2` and have updated the angular.json to build with ESBuild.

```
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser-esbuild",
```

Then when trying to serve the app:

> WARNING: The experimental esbuild-based builder is not currently supported by the dev-server. The stable Webpack-based builder will be used instead.

How do I [configure ESbuild](https://angular.io/guide/esbuild#updating-the-application-configuration) in an Angular app?

Comment: ng build can only run with ESBuild I guess, not ng serve

Comment: Try ng build --watch

Answer (score 9):

"MODERN" ANGULAR: Since angular 16.1

To enable Esbuild, you need to add the following option to your angular.json file, under the “serve” section:

`"forceEsbuild":true`

Then, you can run **“ng serve”** as usual and enjoy the benefits of Esbuild.
It will use Esbuild instead of Webpack to speed up your development process in your app.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

esbuild is not supported in dev server, i.e when you run `ng serve` but supported in build i.e. when you run `ng build`

to use esbuild in development, just build the app normally then use your own server to serve the app

you can use http-server, or any other dev server (for me I use Vite)

here is the complete example:

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "npm run build && npm run serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "serve": "vite serve ./dist/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME --port=4200",
  },
```

note that I replaced `ng serve` with `vite serve` or `http-server ./dist`
to view the build result in the browser run `npm run start:dev`

in both cases, you need to install vite or http-server as devDependencies

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the [doc](https://angular.io/guide/roadmap#investigate-modern-bundles):

In Angular v15 esbuild support only

```
 ng build and ng build --watch
```

Comment: Is ng build --watch not working?